# How to convert Objc c Enum to NSValue in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to pass a to a class a Objective c Enum rapped as NSValue.

I am  using Objective c I would do this like so:

```
   NSValue *orderSide = [NSValue value:&side withObjCType:@encode(enum kOrder_side)];
```

How can I do this is swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var value = NSValue(&side, withObjCType: &(kOrder_side.rawValue))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this line code, it could help you.

```
var orderSide: NSValue = NSValue.value(&side, withObjCType: )
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.